# Is it possible to pause a Batch Script with no message?

Tags: batch-file

I am working on a Windows batch script, and am trying to pause the script for 10 seconds. I have already tried the `timeout` method, however, this displays a message such as:
`Waiting for 10 seconds, press a key to continue ...`

Is it possible to timeout a batch script without showing a message such as the linux sleep command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redirect the timeout output to the nul device:

```
timeout 10 > nul
```